# How should I archecture app to send data from server to iPhone using JSON as medium?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, architecture

I have an iOS application that communicates with web server. For simplicity, the app has only one UITableView and cells only have one UIImageView with a label.

What are the best practices when sending the text data from the server to the device?

I have read that we can just ecode the UIImages from the server and pass it to the device together with the other text like so:

```
text: "someText"
image:"*&TFUNITGH(U*Y&^(*YG ---encodedData"
```

But is this the right approach to send them both together in JSON format? Is there a better way? Basically what i'm asking is, how best do i architecture my app so that I don't shoot my self in the foot when the project gets much larger and more complex? Any advice is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Every time you want to ask what's *best* you get to the opinion side of things. There is very little information there to say anything. How will it be handled? Always changing data? Dynamic images or not? How would the app be more complex? How much data?

Comment: in json i keep links to images

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen basically im not asking for best approach. Ok you know how MVC architecture is a guide line to go by for good app structure? Well in my case i have no idea what people usually do when it comes to JSON data with UIImages. I just needed a guide line since i have zero experience in this. The images will supplied by the server and can change at any time.

Comment: Send images as url and in app side load images in asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one commenter mentioned, the best approach would be:

1. Server sends URL image links
2. App loads the images asynchronously

This works well since the images are usually hosted on some image server for speed.